# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

Issue in **Laravel 5.3.6** when submitted request in Forgot Password.

**Error Details**

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()

**Issue is in below file:**

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php

**Line 69. Code is below**

```
$user->sendPasswordResetNotification(
    $this->tokens->create($user)
);
```

**Function: sendResetLink**

It was working fine in **Laravel 5.2** and seems not working in **5.3.6** version. Have you faced this issue?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You must add `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait in `User` model.

Comment: getting error: (1/1) FatalErrorException
Trait 'Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable' not found

Answer (score 14):

1. Add the Notifiable trait in your User mode.

   `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable`
2. Add this in your app.php:

For your providers:

`Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,`

In the aliases:

`'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,`

3. Remember to update your *from* settings in the *config/mail.php* file.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I was still getting error after following steps given in other answers.

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method 
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()

I was missing

> use Notifiable

```
...
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
class User extends Model
{
     use SoftDeletes, Notifiable;
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you have to do all of the following :

Add the Notifiable trait in your User mode.

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model
{
     use SoftDeletes, Notifiable;
```

Add this in your app.php:

For your providers:

```
Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
```

In the aliases:

```
'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
```

Thanks to Nijesh, Francisco and Bestmomo Momo for their parts of the answer, but I had to do all of the above.