# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify() Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I m using `Laravel 5.4` getting the above `error`

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()

i have came accross  this solution

> You must add Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable trait in User model. (link:[Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::notify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39337964/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-buildernotify))

even though it is not working for me

Below is my `User` `model`  i haven't created any folder for `models` its path is default

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    use Notifiable;         

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','phone','address','google_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }  
}
```

> during getting above error my current url is
>   http://localhost:8000/password/email

[image]

i have tried many previous `versions` solution but still does not work?

**UPDATE 1: HERE IS MY PROJECT ON DROPBOX**  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jr6ls6xo7flbv8/myproject.zip?dl=0

My interest is only `password reset` `http://localhost:8000/password/reset`  (where i'm getting error)

Please Help Me To Get Rid Of This Error Thanks in Adavce!!!

Please Help Me To Get Rid Of This Error Thanks in Adavce!!!

Comment: Have you done everything listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40314170/1287695 ?

Comment: @kjones,yes i have tried those thing mentioned there

Comment: i have uploaded my project on `drop box`  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8jr6ls6xo7flbv8/myproject.zip?dl=0  please hit this url to test it http://localhost:8000/password/reset

Comment: @EaB i have seen your code where you trying to notify a user?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz, i'm trying to use the default forgot password functionality which is built-in in laravel.  if you have any solution please post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have duplicate files ?!

Delete `User (2).php` and `Category (2).php`

For some reason, file User (2).php, which does not have the Notify trait is the one loaded. Thus, you got this error.

Just delete the extra files.

Comment: Great Great !!! it worked for me after Deleting `User(2).php` and `Category(2).php`  Then `php artisan cache:clear`  and then `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: i struggled a lot to get `answer` for this `question` i have to `edit` `question` every hour to reach more audiences after crossing `101 view` i got the answer thanks alot

Comment: Never thought about that `Laravel` will `look` for `User(2).php` instead `User.php`

Comment: You're welcome. It's composer loading the files not laravel. 
It's wired to me that this file is matched to the User class when it's does not have the same name. I bet because of the space in the file name, composer treat the file as User.php.

Try to be careful about the files you include in your project. It looks like you were trying to keep unmodified copy of the files to refer to. Try to store them outside of your project. Yet better, use Git and be a real developer. Good luck.